# postgres make a function that returns rows with composite type

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables, A and B, I'd like to make a function that returns their natural join.

Here is a function that returns the entirety of table A

```
create function func() returns setof A as 'select * from A;' language sql;
```

I'd like to find a way to do their natural join, here is what I have so far:

```
create function func() returns setof A as 'select * from A natural join B;' language sql;
```

The problem is that the types don't match, what can I change so that the types match? Thanks

Comment: 1. Do you really need all those fields from both tables? 2. If you want a composite type, it will have to contain all the fields that are returned by the query. 3. You could also just do something like `RETURNS TABLE (field1 INTEGER, field2 TEXT, ...)` to return all the fields you want without creating a composite type.

Comment: what I want is to know in general how to determine the schema of the output of a function. This is just a particular example I came up with to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: So, either create a composite type with all the returned fields, or return a TABLE with all the field names and types specified there, without creating a composite type.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try using TABLE as you mentioned